# mongoose.model( 'Foo', FooSchema ) vs require( './models/Foos' )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Once a schema is created, and placed within the models folder. A line of code is added as such...

```
// within '/models/Foos.js'
mongoose.model( 'Foo', FooSchema )
```

... but a reference to this schema is also added within node's app.js, as such...

```
var mongoose = require( 'mongoose' );
require( './models/Foos' )
```

... but what's the difference? Why do we have the need to do the latter (i.e. add schema file reference to global mongoose object within app.js), when we have already done something seemingly similar, within the schema file itself (i.e. FoosSchema.js), by `mongoose.model( 'Foo', FooSchema )`. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)` line registers the model globally inside `mongoose`, which means it is possible to get the model via `mongoose.model('Foo')` anywhere inside the application. However, the model `Foo` is registered only after the `foos.js` is `require`'d inside the application. Therefore you still need to require the file somewhere, hence the line `require( './models/Foos' )`

EDIT: use a loop to require every file inside a model directory.

```
var normalizedPath = require('path').join(__dirname, "./models");
require("fs").readdirSync(normalizedPath).forEach(function(file) {
  require("./models/" + file);
});
```

Comment: Okay, I get that. However, to me it still seems like redundancy. Once you have linked the schema to mongoose, it should be able to work out the references automatically. Strange.

Comment: Yes, but you need to actually run the code that links the schema to mongoose. How would you run that code without requiring the actual file? There are other ways to set it up, but all of them will at the very least involve requiring the file containing the schema.

Comment: Hmmm, perhaps we should just have the need to add the file location... and mongoose should then be able to work out the model... no?

Comment: A common approach, is you have a folder containing all of your schemas, where each file also registers the model like you've already done `mongoose.model('ModelName', Schema)`. Then you write a simple for loop, that goes through the model directory in question, and simply `require`s every file. That way every new model file you create inside that directory will be automatically registered in mongoose. I'll edit my answer and put an example there.

Comment: Oh, thanks for the "best practice". But honestly, I still can't seem to be able to convince my self against it being redundant. It's probably because I am lacking something here... a jigsaw piece is still missing. I mean would there potentially be any circumstances where one is needed but not the other. So for example, you would need to `require` the file, but have no need to add schema to global mongoose internally with `mongoose.model`?

Comment: Yeah, that is definitely a possibility on some projects (the one I'm on right now, actually does that). It is typically an issue when you need to create several instances of mongoose, that connect to different databases, but you still want to re-use the same schemas. In those cases, what you do is you each file exports a plain javascript object, which will ultimately be your schema. e.g. `module.exports = {name: String, location: String}`. Then you create a custom function that requires the files and  calls `new mongoose.Schema` and registers the model `mongoose.model(..)`.

Comment: In most projects this isn't a concrete requirement (which is why I didn't mention it), but if you have a more complex server or schema setup, then yes, each file should ultimately just export a javascript object, and instantiate the schema and model in another part of the app as needed.

Comment: Okay, but what I understand from your explanation is that whether the model is added within the same schema file or elsewhere... each model still needs to be `require`d and `mongoose.model`d. Hence, my original confusion remains. Once you add a reference to the file (`require`), mongoose should be able to figure out the model. Especially, if both are required everytime.

Comment: I think there is some misunderstanding, and correct me if I'm wrong, but I get the feeling that you are under the impression you need to require the file everytime in order to have access to the model. That is not the case. You only need to require the file in question once. After `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)` gets executed, `mongoose.model('Foo')` may be called anywhere without requiring the file again. The file containing the model is only require'd at the beginning of the program. In your services or controller you may call `mongoose.model('Foo')` without `require('/models/foo')`

Comment: In other words you're really just calling `require('./models/foo')` in order to globally register the model at the beginning of the program. Mongoose will thereafter remember that you registered the model.

Comment: First of all, I really appreciate the fact that you are still putting in the effort to make this comprehensible to me. Thanks.

Regarding the impression, actually no. I understand that it has to be done only once. But what I just can't get my head around is that why mongoose would still require you to manually add the model, although you have already registered the file via `require`. I just think, with my limited understanding, that after you have `require`d... mongoose should be able to work out that you need to add the model implicitly.

Comment: I don't understand why it makes you do it manually... unless ofcourse there was a scenario whereby you would need to `require` but not `mongoose.model` eventually. But from I understand so far, is that you would eventually need both. So why the need for explicit addition, when it can be done automatically.

Comment: Let's walkthrough what happens when you start the server. Suppose you have a file called `server.js`, this is the file you call `node server.js` on. In the beginning of the file you call `var mongoose = require('mongoose')` this is the first time mongoose has been called, no models have yet to be registered. Now at this time, the program has only loaded `server.js`, so if you call `mongoose.model('Foo')`, you will get an error. because the model has not been registered. How would mongoose know to register `Foo`? You haven't required the file containing the `Foo` model.

Comment: Mongoose can't just predict where you defined the `Foo` model. So you have to require the file containing that model. So once you call `require('/models/foo')`, and inside it call `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)`, mongoose will then remember that you've defined this model. Thereafter calling `mongoose.model('Foo')` will return the model that you've defined inside `foo.js`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, but I guess I wasn't clear enough. What I meant was that once you require the file... mongoose already has access to model. Why does it need for us to say mongoose.model('Foo') if it can do it by itself.

Comment: Can you explain, what you think `mongoose.model('Foo')` actually does? I think this is the misunderstanding. When you call `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)`, that is the point when the model is registered/set. When you call `mongoose.model('Foo')`, it GETS the model (it HAS to be registered at this point, else throws error), in other words, it returns a reference to the model constructor. This reference is what you use to actually make the model do things. For instance, you can do `var Foo = mongoose.model('Foo');  Foo.find({name: 'Bob'}, function(err, res){})`

Comment: I think this conversation is going in the wrong direction, so we better stop. But yes, I know `mongoose.model('Foo')` gets the model. What I was trying to ask in my previous questions was that after you have done `require('/models/foo')`, mongoose should not need to ask for `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)`. I was not talking about getting the model... I was talking about the need for registering the model manually, although you have already given reference via require. Mongoose should be able to work out `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)` by itself. Anyway.. enough said.

Comment: Okay, I understand what you're trying to say. But, I'm not sure why you think mongoose should not need to ask for `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)` to be called. There's no way it can know to register, that specific instance of schema, to the model designated by the string 'Foo', without being told explcitly. How do you figure it would happen?

Comment: Aaaaaaaaah! I think the penny just dropped :). So the need for  `mongoose.model('Foo', FooSchema)` is there because otherwise you would not have a string identifier to refer to it by, later when making the 'mongoose.model( 'Foo' )` call. Oh thank you so much Yuri. I wish I could buy you a coffee :)

Comment: Np, glad I could help,  I could use a coffee right about now :)

Answer (score 2):

Well actually it can be just:

```
var Foo = mongoose.model( 'Foo' );
```

After the initial model declaration has been made, which will just retrieve the specified model with it's already attached schema, and of course that you already have a `require` for `mongoose` at least within the scope.

Equally you could just use it completely inline:

```
mongoose.model( 'Foo' ).find({},function(err,foos) {
    // do something
});
```

In the end the "two" approaches with either using `require` for your defined module and the `mongoose.model` accessor generally achieve the same thing. The main "difference" being that `require` is "path centric" to the structure of your application. Where as `mongoose.model` is inspecting mongoose's own "registry" of defined model data and retrieving the required "service" by name.

Therefore using `mongoose.model` may be considered "cleaner" in a lot of cases, but on the other hand `require` may be more along the logic of other module imports that others are used to in style.

This really comes down to coding patterns and style as to which best suits you. Though as "name based", the `mongoose.model` style does lend itself a bit more readily to "dynamic" code to recall the required model, as compared to importing from a "path" in your application.

Consider this:

```
async.each(['Foo','Bar'],function(modelName,callback) {
    mongoose.model(modelName).remove({},callback);
},function(err) { 
   //done 
});
```

As an example of a programtic call that does not need `require` for a registered model.

Comment: Thank you for trying to answer me. I appreciate it.

Comment: @Grateful Are you at least familar with dependency injection and service resolution? General principles is that rather than requiring a "module" explictly, you ask a "registry" for the "service by name". That is the primary analog which I am trying to point out here.

Comment: Yes, I think so. Thanks.